# Set checkbox to indeterminate

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I have a requirement where if checkbox current state is indeterminate then user clicks it, then state changes to checked, again clicks on it(means second click) it should set to indeterminate instead of unchecked. Any idea how to do that.

Comment: which version of angular material  you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the `onChange` method that will set the right value for `MatCheckbox`'s `intermediate` property.

```
onChange(checkbox: MatCheckbox): void {
    this.isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    checkbox.indeterminate = !this.isChecked;
}
```

Here is your template code fragment

```
<mat-checkbox indeterminate="true" #myChecker [checked]="isChecked" (change)="onChange(myChecker);">Tick me off</mat-checkbox>
```

But do not forget to import the `MatCheckbox`.

```
import { MatCheckbox } from "@angular/material";
```